# What are some possible causes for CPU Spikes in AWS that are resolved by a new deployment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, cpu-usage

I have several enterprise applications in AWS ECS built in Java that begin to incur high CPU usage - I mean a large spike - and it continues until I re-release. The code version can be exactly the same, but for some reason, by releasing and renewing the resources, the CPU goes back down to a sane level.

What are some possible causes of a scenario like this? There is no memory spike to correlate the CPU spikes with. It is not a code issue because different applications with completely different code bases experience the same symptoms. But obviously not all applications have this issue, so it is a tangible, solvable problem (not a "bug" in AWS).

What techniques can I use to diagnose and once and for all fix this wide spread problem in our services? If it involves a CPU dump, what would one look for, and what indications would I expect to see that would point to specific problems?

Comment: I would start with an APM solution like new relic.

Comment: Recording and analyzing metrics is a powerful and useful methodology which we do employ, but using those metrics correctly is key. What metrics specifically would one look for in this situation? I am privy to almost all aspects of my applications performance, errors, and usage - but it's all a giant haystack and I don't even know if I am looking for a needle.

Comment: Are you using instance types which use CPU credits, such as t2.* or t3.*?